# Как построить массив массивов, чтобы значения у них не повторялись?

Tags: графы, дерево, php, комбинаторика, graph

Существует 3 массива:

```
$name = array('foo','bar');  
$os   = array('win','linux');  
$arch = array('x86','x64');
```

Сколько различных комбинаций(массивов) можно получить?

Считаем: $name(2 шт.) * $os (2 шт.) * $arch (2 шт.) = 8 вариантов

Смотрим дерево:

[image]

В конечном варианте нужно получить:

```
$graph = array(  
    array('foo', 'win', 'x86'),  
    array('foo', 'win', 'x64'),  
    array('foo', 'linux', 'x86'),  
    array('foo', 'linux', 'x64'),  
    array('bar', 'win', 'x86'),  
    array('bar', 'win', 'x64'),  
    array('bar', 'linux', 'x86'),  
    array('bar', 'linux', 'x64')
);
```

Как такой массив можно реализовать на PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$name = array('foo','bar');  
$os   = array('win','linux');  
$arch = array('x86','x64');
$result = array();

foreach ($name as $name_value) {
    foreach ($os as $os_value) {
        foreach ($arch as $arch_value) {
            $result[] = array($name_value, $os_value, $arch_value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!